# How to solve observable problem with firebase login authentication in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, observable

I have a stupid bug in my code that I need to login two times for login to work. Even though it works first time because after first login it prints out in the console the user details which is observable `private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;`

My other logic in login method doesn't work, like:

```
if (this.userDetails) {
email = this.userDetails.email;
console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
```

first time this gives me undefined because it looks like this code gets called before observable returns `userDetails`. How to avoid this? How to get around this? Here is my ***Auth service code***

```
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;
  public loggedIn = false;



  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('user');

    this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.userDetails = user;

            console.log(this.userDetails);
          } else {
            this.userDetails = null;
          }
        }
      );
  }

  // Set current user in your session after a successful login
    setCurrentUser(email: string): void {
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', email);
        this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    // Get currently logged in user from session
    getCurrentUser(): string | any {
        return sessionStorage.getItem('user') || undefined;
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
    }

  logUserIn(email, pass) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
console.log("error" + error);
})
//var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (this.userDetails) {
email = this.userDetails.email;
console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);

this.setCurrentUser(email);
 this.loggedIn = true;
} else {
console.log("not working");
}

this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

Before using observable tho get `userDetails`, I was just using `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` and it was working just fine.

So I'm looking for a help to make sure this block of code

```
if (this.userDetails) {
    email = this.userDetails.email;
    console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);

    this.setCurrentUser(email);
     this.loggedIn = true;
```

inside `logUserin()` gets called only after `userDetails` observable is returned.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that if statement in your subscription so that it only calls once user has returned.

```
this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.userDetails = user;

    email = this.userDetails.email;
    console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);

    this.setCurrentUser(email);
     this.loggedIn = true;

            console.log(this.userDetails);
          } else {
            this.userDetails = null;
          }
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Not Angular but Nuxt.js

You had better get observable user when you get user.
like this

##### rxfire helps you.

```
import { doc } from "rxfire/firestore"

//maek func for getUser

  getUser(userId: string): Observable<AppUser> {

    //doc is from rxfire
    const doc$ = doc(this.getRef(userId))
    doc$.pipe(
      map(snapshot => {
        const user = snapshot.data() as IUserEntity
        const appUser = { ...user, id: doc$.id}
        return appUser
      })
    )
  }
```

appUser is just use in my application for using firebase_id.

```
export interface AppUser extends IUserEntity {
  id : string
}
```